# Is there a an event for the currency exchange rates?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, currency, multicurrency, currency-rates

I would like to observe the event when the exchange rates are fetched from Webservicex. Is there such an event that I can observe? I haven't been able to find one in the docs and am not too happy with setting a up a cron.

Comment: What do you need to do with it? There is not one on the fetch but you can hook into the save.

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm seeing in `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency_Import_Abstract` and `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency_Import_Webservicex` and the whole Mage_Directory module, there is no `dispatchEvent()` method included. You could just hook on events from basic save/update methods then.

You did not mention what you're trying to achieve but as a general advice, best practise in this case would be to extend the class on your own, put your own events in and observe them.

Comment: I have an extension that notifies a third-party site about changes in the exchange rate, by calling an API. I guess observing the `directory_currency_save_after` event of the currency model will easily suffice for the  need.

Comment: It looks like the WebServiceX doesn't dispatch any save events as it saved directly through the currency resource model bypassing any model saves. This doesn't seem possible unfortunately.